# Re-sample for each iteration of a loop & storing calculated stats for each iteration in a matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I need to write a for loop that re-samples a rgamma(100,1,2), calculates sample stats (mean, sd, range), and stores them in a matrix for in each iteration. I've read a lot of for-loop documentation and I can see how a loop would work for changing the sample size in each iteration, but not re-sampling the same sample size. I think I may also be writing over my results in the matrix, but I'm not sure how to fix it. So far I have:

```
new_data <- rgamma(100,1,2)
ITER <- 1000
results = matrix(c(0), nrow = ITER, ncol = 5)

for (i in 1:ITER){
    d<- new_data(i)
    j = mean(d)
    k = sd(d)
    l = max(d) - min(d)
    m = quantile(d)[[4]]
    results[k,] <- results[i,j,k,l,m]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing was off. Also, you have to create a new sample within the for-loop, otherwise the exercise does not make sense. Here is a working example:

```
ITER <- 1000
results = matrix(c(0), nrow = ITER, ncol = 4)

for (i in 1:ITER){
  new_data <- rgamma(100,1,2)
  j = mean(new_data)
  k = sd(new_data)
  l = max(new_data) - min(new_data)
  m = quantile(new_data)[[4]]
  results[i,] <- c(j,k,l,m)
}
```